# Not able to receive Set-Cookie field using RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, cookies, resttemplate

I am trying two ways to POST on a url and everything is working fine except in one field.

If i am using HttpConnection i am receiving Set-Cookie field as output.

```
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("username", "1010101010");
    json.put("password", "11two33");
    String loginContent = json.toString();
    int timeOut = 100000;
    String authLoginUrl = "http://localhost:8080/api/login";

    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");

    HttpExternalService httpService = new HttpExternalService();
    HttpExResponseDetails exResponse = httpService.sendRequest(authLoginUrl, loginContent, HttpMethod.POST, timeOut,
            headers, null, null, true, true, true, false, null);

    Map<String, List<String>> rsHeaders = exResponse.getResponseHeaderMap();
    for(Entry<String, List<String>> e: rsHeaders.entrySet()){
        System.out.println("Key: "+e.getKey());
        List<String> valueList = e.getValue();
        for(String str: valueList){
            System.out.println("Value: "+str);
        }
    }
```

That is one field that is coming in the output:

OUTPUT:

```
Key: Transfer-Encoding
Value: chunked
Key: null
Value: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Key: Server
Value: Jetty(9.2.16.v20160414)
Key: X-Content-Type-Options
Value: nosniff
Key: Pragma
Value: no-cache
Key: X-Application-Context
Value: gateway:8080
Key: Date
Value: Wed, 13 Jul 2016 14:08:55 GMT
Key: Via
Value: 1.1 d.eze.cc
Key: X-Frame-Options
Value: DENY
Key: Cache-Control
Value: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Key: Vary
Value: Accept-Encoding
Key: Set-Cookie
Value: jsessionid=c5bcc245-e18e-4320-8ac2-08b3e51dcae7;Path=/api/;HttpOnly
Key: Expires
Value: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Key: X-XSS-Protection
Value: 1; mode=block
Key: Content-Type
Value: application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

But if i am using RestTemplate for hitting the same url i am not receiving any Set-Cookie field which is a strange behaviour.

```
    Map<String, String> json = new HashMap<String, String>();
    json.put("username", "1010101010");
    json.put("password", "11two33");

    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");

    ResponseEntity<ApiOutput> out = WebServiceCaller.postServiceCall(url, ApiOutput.class, json, null);
    // HttpExResponseDetails exResponse =
    // httpService.sendRequest(authLoginUrl, loginContent, HttpMethod.POST,
    // timeOut,
    // getHeaders(), null, null, true, false, false, false, null);
    System.out.println("Status code: " + out.getStatusCode());
    MultiValueMap<String, String> rsHeaders = out.getHeaders();

    for (Entry<String, List<String>> e : rsHeaders.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Key: " + e.getKey());
        List<String> valueList = e.getValue();
        for (String str : valueList) {
            System.out.println("Value: " + str);
        }
    }
```

Response:

```
    Status code: 200
    Key: Date
    Value: Wed, 13 Jul 2016 14:06:43 GMT
    Key: Server
    Value: Jetty(9.2.16.v20160414)
    Key: X-Application-Context
    Value: gateway:8080
    Key: X-Content-Type-Options
    Value: nosniff
    Key: X-XSS-Protection
    Value: 1; mode=block
    Key: Cache-Control
    Value: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
    Key: Pragma
    Value: no-cache
    Key: Expires
    Value: 0
    Key: X-Frame-Options
    Value: DENY
    Key: Content-Type
    Value: application/json; charset=UTF-8
    Key: Via
    Value: 1.1 localhost:8080
    Key: Vary
    Value: Accept-Encoding
    Key: Transfer-Encoding
    Value: chunked
```

The RestTemplate code that i am using to get this:

```
public static <T> ResponseEntity<T> postServiceCall(String url, Class<T> responseType,
            Object postBody,MultiValueMap<String, String> headers) {
        HttpEntity<Object> request = new HttpEntity<Object>(postBody, headers);
        ResponseEntity<T> response=restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, request,responseType);
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution for this please ? I am getting the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what's `WebServiceCaller` does, however [`RestTemplate#exchange`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#exchange-org.springframework.http.RequestEntity-java.lang.Class-) should return all the headers.

Comment: That's the problem I am not receiving it

Comment: I have added complete output from the requests

Comment: Which method from `RestTemplate` class are you using in order to call your endpoint?

Comment: I have added that in the question now.